# Tolkien-inspired: who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I can walk on the floor, I can walk on the wall
>
> Under trees, on top of hills slowly I do crawl
>
> Back and forth, back and forth, I stalk the streets at night
>
> If I fall I make no sound, but sometimes quite a fright

Who am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer:

> The Shadow

I can walk on the floor, I can walk on the wall

> When you walk your shadow is on the floor and on the wall

Under trees, on top of hills slowly I do crawl

> The shadow is crawled under trees and on top of hills

Back and forth, back and forth, I stalk the streets at night

> The shadow appears more during night

If I fall I make no sound, but sometimes quite a fright

> Someone is frightened from the shadow but the shadow makes no sound

Comment: To me the back and forth could be due to cars passing.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox, The back and forth could reference the change in the angle of a shadow between street lamps.

Comment: By the way, what is the "shadow" on top of hills? Clouds!

Answer (score 4):

I think it's:

> Darkness (as in shadows and darkness of the night).

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I read Tolkien but if I remember correctly one of the major creatures in the stories were the giant

> SPIDERS who descended from one great spider and they could walk on walls, floors etc and they were especially feared in the dark.

Comment: It's Tolkien-inspired not Tolkien-related.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is:

> Moonlight

I can walk on the floor, I can walk on the wall:

> As the moon rises or sets, the light cast can travel along the wall/floor.

Under trees, on top of hills slowly I do crawl:

> Under trees, the light is obstructed and doesn't travel as quickly. On a hilltop there is nothing to obstruct the light so it does not 'move' along rapidly.

Back and forth, back and forth, I stalk the streets at night:

> The moon is visible at night, and the amount of light depends on the phase. The phase varies back and forth.

If I fall I make no sound, but sometimes quite a fright:

> Moonlight falling does not make noise, but may frighten someone who does not expect the lighting to change (e.g. if a cloud was obstructing it and moves).

Answer (score 1):

You are

> an ant

because

> when indoors, you literally **walk on floors and walls**, and only very rarely on ceilings.
>
>  Your nest is an ant**hill** often **under a tree**, and your movement is **slow crawling**.
>
>  Many common ant species (especially in hotter environments) are nocturnal: the workers usually **come out of the nest only at night**, when they tend to **walk back and forth along ant trails**.
>
>  When an ant falls, it definitely makes a sound, but it is too faint to hear if there is any noise around. Humans are easily startled though, so a sudden appearance of an ant seemingly out of nowhere can probably frighten someone, especially if said ant happens to fall on their person.

The answer with the tick, in my opinion, fails to account for the ”on top of hills” bit. Under trees, yes, but very much under *any* trees, and not only those that are on top of hills. A treeless hilltop, on the other hand, is one of the few places where you would *not* expect to see the thing given as the answer.

Comment: See my comment to Yass' answer...

Comment: Well, yes, one could conceivably call clouds ”shadows crawling on top of hills”.  An ant crawling on top of an anthill fits the clue with much less poetic license though, wouldn’t you agree?

Comment: I read your answer again, and your explanation is excellent! Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer is

> Cloud

Because

> Cloud can *walk* on floor or on a wall as it is permeable
>  Under trees(on top of a mountain) and on top of hills a cloud usually crawls
>  Staking in the streets ( to be provided)
>  A cloud when falls/lands on the ground it does so quietly though sometimes it results in **cloud burst** which is frightening.

Comment: I've neve ever ever ever seen a cloud under a tree before.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - Actually, when clouds get so low they touch the ground, they're called "fog". :) So, _technically_ that would be correct, although I doubt it's what the OP had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

> **Fog/Mist** , as it can float around on wall or above floor; creates no sound but can be spooky when it falls and stalks around at nights; Mostly seen on hills under trees due to humidity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> Water

```
I can walk on the floor, I can walk on the wall
Under trees, on top of hills slowly I do crawl
Back and forth, back and forth, I stalk the streets at night
If I fall I make no sound, but sometimes quite a fright
```

I can walk on the floor, I can walk on the wall

> water runs on the floor and walls in rainy season

Under trees, on top of hills slowly I do crawl

> the water is crawled under trees and top of hills(frozen state start melting)

Back and forth, back and forth, I stalk the streets at night

> not thought a good translation

If i fall i make no sound, but sometimes quite a fright

> not thought a good translation

Answer (score 0):

is it

> cat. They walk on walls and come at night, jump from heights and are scary.